# JetBrains, team projects, gitignore

Tags: git, version-control, ide, jetbrains-ide

Despite having done this operation many times, I still encounter problems and get problems.

How am I supposed to set up a repository meant to be worked on by multiple people, considering they will use JetBrains IDE (PyCharm, CLion, IntelliJ, etc.) ?

I've understood that `.idea/` is generally a folder to be mentioned in the `.gitignore`, especially `.idea/workspace.xml`, but there are actually a few files in that folder that are required for the IDE when it comes to being able to open a freshly cloned repo. Yet when I look into which files might be required, I end up finding things related to the specific path of where the project is located within my own computer's path.

The solution I've found so far is to upload all the files of the project in the repository at first, and to add certain files and folders in the `.gitignore` afterward. However, then comes the annoying thing where if you've committed, say, your `.idea/workspace.xml` file once in the repository, even if you add the file in the list of files to be ignored for subsequent pushes, Git will keep stashing the file: you actually need to have had one commit which removed the file *before* adding the rule in the `.gitignore` and *then* adding it back.

What is the way? Please enlighten me, this is absolutely annoying.

Comment: IMHO, a software project should not be IDE dependent so I would keep everything related to IntelliJ Idea out of the project (so .idea would land in my .gitignore, if it were up to me).

Comment: @eftshift0 sure, but then what is the *ultimate* `.gitignore` that will keep any repository agnostic to every single IDE possible (Eclipse, etc.)?

Comment: Add the necessary rules for each one.... or a generic one that will have to be broken (with a `git add -f some-file`) every once in a while like: `.*` (that is, assuming that all IDEs use hidden files and directories to save their stuff).